# ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=1

Tags: node.js, gpu, error-code

Running electron app is working as i expected, but when pc is for a day or two turned on... with app open then i get this error:

```
[11276:0816/234656.781:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(991)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=1
[11276:0816/234656.791:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(521)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
```

Also the app window become black when maximilize or open from tray, but only after a time...one or two days that app is open and working as expected...

My computer performance:

Procesor i5, 12 generation with 64GB RAM, Integrated video graphic, 4TB disck space.

I wish to share the main code but is to big, thare are only commands for emiting from main.js and reciving data from render.js

I don't understand why after a while get this error and why the black screen.

Any answers are welcome!

I checked my code, no errors, nor bugs, i tried to restart the app but the problem persist! I have to restart the pc and or to reinstall node modules, the the app starting again...

Comment: i forgot to mention that the app have two proccesses with timeOut function wich is set to 4000 milisecound, i m not sure if this can be a issue ...